# how create process child run method while True in python use multiprocessing?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, fork

i want run two process child as

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def method(namelog):
    filelog  = open(namelog,'w')
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        filelog.write('test log anything \n')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=method, args=('log1.log',))
    print "start process1"
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=method, args=('log2.log',))
    print "start process2"
    p2.start()
```

result :

```
start process1
start process2

program create 2 file log1.log and log2.log
but not save data
```

i thing process created but it not work
help me !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close your file for writing. Note that I changed the mode in `open()` from write to append.

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def method(namelog):
    while True:
        with open(namelog,'a') as filelog:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            filelog.write('test log anything \n')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=method, args=('log1.log',))
    print "start process1"
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=method, args=('log2.log',))
    print "start process2"
    p2.start()
```